# How to create an animation that consists of a fragment overlapping another one?

Tags: android, animation, navigation, transition, effect

I am using the navigation component and I want to create an animation that consists of a fragment that slides and overlaps the other one. It's like this picture:

[image: fragment overlapping anotherone]

I don't find the way to achieve it. I know how to make the fragments slide but I don't know how to achieve the same that is in this picture.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Navigation Components allows to specify `enterAnim` and `exitAnim` for each action.
By defining the  `enterAnim` to slide from the right and the `exitAnim` to f.e. fade out, you will get such an effect.

Check out this guide on how to set up the animations:
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-animate-transitions

[image: Navigation-Animations]